# Is a dashed border around a selected text/image element possible in Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, image, silverlight, border, frameworkelement

I have an image editor I'm developing in silverlight which has multiple text and image elements on one canvas, that are draggable etc. I need feedback for the user to highlight the selected element when it is clicked on by the user and highlight a different element instead if another is clicked. I think I should do this with a dashed border around the element, but I don't know if it's possible.

Below is my code relating to the elements -

Project.cs

```
namespace ImageEditor.Client.BLL
{
 public class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
    private int numberOfElements;

    #region Properties

    private ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> elements;
    public ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> Elements
    {
        get { return elements; }
        set
        {
            elements = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Elements");
        }
    }


    private FrameworkElement selectedElement;
    public FrameworkElement SelectedElement
    {
        get { return selectedElement; }
        set
        {
            selectedElement = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedElement");

        }
    }


    private TextBlock selectedTextElement;
    public TextBlock SelectedTextElement
    {
        get { return selectedTextElement; }
        set
        {
            selectedTextElement = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTextElement");
        }
    }

    private Image selectedImageElement;
    public Image SelectedImageElement
    {
        get { return selectedImageElement; }
        set
        {
            selectedImageElement = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedImageElement");
        }
    }

    #endregion


    #region Methods

    private void AddTextElement(object param)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
        textBlock.Text = "New Text";
        textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        textBlock.FontSize = 25;
        textBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        textBlock.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        textBlock.Tag = null;

        AddDraggingBehavior(textBlock);
        textBlock.MouseLeftButtonUp += element_MouseLeftButtonUp;

        this.Elements.Add(textBlock);
        numberOfElements++;

        this.SelectedElement = textBlock;
        this.selectedTextElement = textBlock;
    }

    private BitmapImage GetImageFromLocalMachine(out bool? success, out string fileName)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog()
        {
            Filter = "Image Files (*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;)|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;",
            Multiselect = false
        };

        success = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (success == true)
        {
            fileName = dialog.File.Name;
            FileStream stream = dialog.File.OpenRead();
            byte[] data;

            BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage();
            using (FileStream fileStream = stream)
            {
                imageSource.SetSource(fileStream);
                data = new byte[fileStream.Length];
                fileStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                fileStream.Flush();
                fileStream.Close();
            }

            return imageSource;
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = string.Empty;
            return new BitmapImage();
        }
    }

    private void AddImageElement(object param)
    {
        bool? gotImage;
        string fileName;
        BitmapImage imageSource = GetImageFromLocalMachine(out gotImage, out fileName);

        if (gotImage == true)
        {
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Name = fileName;
            image.Source = imageSource;
            image.Height = imageSource.PixelHeight;
            image.Width = imageSource.PixelWidth;
            image.MaxHeight = imageSource.PixelHeight;
            image.MaxWidth = imageSource.PixelWidth;
            image.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            image.Tag = null;


            AddDraggingBehavior(image);
            image.MouseLeftButtonUp += element_MouseLeftButtonUp;

            this.Elements.Add(image);
            numberOfElements++;

            this.SelectedElement = image;
            this.SelectedImageElement = image;
        }
    }


    private void OrderElements()
    {
        var elList = (from element in this.Elements
                      orderby element.GetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty)
                      select element).ToList<FrameworkElement>();

        for (int i = 0; i < elList.Count; i++)
        {
            FrameworkElement fe = elList[i];
            fe.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, i);
        }

        this.Elements = new ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>(elList);
    }

    public void element_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectedElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (sender is TextBlock)
        {
            this.SelectedTextElement = sender as TextBlock;
            FadeOut(this.SelectedTextElement);
        }
        else if (sender is Image)
        {
            this.SelectedImageElement = sender as Image;
            FadeOut(this.SelectedImageElement);
        }

    }
    #endregion
```

More than needed there but you get a good idea of how it all works from that. How might I go about it? I'm still pretty new to silverlight

Edit:

This is my start attempt at a DashBorder Method, wherein I'm trying to make a rectangle the same dimensions as the selected element which will go around the element

```
public static void DashBorder(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        rect.Width=element.Width;
        rect.Height=element.Height;
        rect.StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection() { 2, 2 };

    }
```

It appears to do nothing and isn't what I want to do anyway. Is there no way to make a dash border on a FrameworkElement directly?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the rectangle...  Also, no, I'm pretty sure you can't add a dashed border to a frameworkelement directly.  You have to use an element that allows dashed borders either directly or as part of the control template.

Comment: Notice that `StrokeDashArray` is explicitly a property on a `Shape` object.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.strokedasharray(v=vs.95)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how, [but google does](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/5574.aspx).

> You can use the StrokeDashArray to achieve the desired effect,
>   example:

`<Rectangle Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="100" Height="100"
         Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="10, 2"/>`

> The first number in StrokeDashArray is the length of the dash, the
>   second number is the length of the gap. You can repeat the dash gap
>   pairs to generate different patterns.

Edit:

To do this in code create a rectangle and set it's `StrokeDashArray` property like this (code untested):

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.StrokeThickness = 1;
double[] dashArray = new double[2];
dashArray[0] = 2;
dashArray[1] = 4;
rect.StrokeDashArray = dashArray;
```

Comment: I knew about the strokedasharray. I can't do it in XAML though as the elements are added programatically and I need to add the border programatically when te element is clicked and removed when something else is

Comment: Would this kind of thing work to put the element on my image/text framework element?`public static void DashBorder(FrameworkElement element)
  {
   element.StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection() { 2, 2 };
  }`

Comment: It has to be a shape: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.strokedasharray(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: It just tells me that System.Windows.FrameworkElement  does not contain a definition for StrokeDashArray. I tried your code and got the same, even when it was a rectangle. I am using ImageTools

Comment: I mean i got "ImageTools.Rectangle does not contain a definition for StrokeDashArray...." when I used your code

Comment: I'm going to guess that `ImageTools.Rectangle` does not inherit from `Shape`.  You need to use the build-in `Rectangle` not a custom library `Rectangle`.

Comment: You were right about ImageTools, Shapes.rectangle is fine. but i don't see any sign of it working at the same time. I edited my original question above with the code